# Passing additional arguments to ST_MapAlgebra callback?

Tags: postgis, raster, map-algebra

I've written a custom callback function for `ST_MapAlgebra` and I want to pass additional arguments to it. The function is pretty useless - it just generates a raster filled with normal random values according to a user-specified mean and standard deviation.

I tried including the extra arguments in the string, like so:

```
...
ST_MapAlgebra(
    b1.rast, -- raster to operate on
    1,
    'generate_random_raster(double precision[][][], integer[][],  ''3'', ''1'')'::regprocedure
  ),
...
```

And like this:

```
...
ST_MapAlgebra(
    b1.rast, -- raster to operate on
    1,
    'generate_random_raster(double precision[][][], integer[][],  VARIADIC ARRAY[3,5]::text')'::regprocedure
  ),
...
```

It works fine if I hard code the values I want to use, so the callback itself isn't a problem.

#### How do I pass additional arguments to a custom `ST_MapAlgebra` function?

Comment: Excellent question. The ST_MapAlgebra function is very powerful, but not super well documented. There is a very entertaining and completely nuts blog post from [Boston GIS](http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/234-PostGIS-Day-Game-of-Life-celebration.html) that is the best treatment i have seen on this subject.

Comment: I've been working on changing that a bit - I'm new to this and I want to help smooth out the learning curve for other newbies. I've written [a couple examples](https://nronnei.github.io/blog/tags/raster-math-series/) if you'd like to check them out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Additional arguments are passed as the 6th, and so on, arguments, after the custom function signature:

```
ST_MapAlgebra(b1.rast, -- raster to operate on
              1, -- band
              'generate_random_raster(double precision[], integer[], text[])'::regprocedure, -- custom function signature
              pixeltype, -- can be null
              extenttype, -- can be null
              customextent, -- can be null
              distancex, -- can be null
              distancey, -- can be null
              firstextraargument,
              secondextraargument,
              ...
  )
```

Some demo scripts can be found on [github](https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons/blob/master/postgis_addons.sql).

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the variadic args

Comment: I was indeed referring to the variadic arguments.

Comment: firstextraargument and secondextraargument are variadic arguments.

Comment: If you could provide an example of actually using them, it would be really useful. It is an area where the docs are a bit sparse.

Comment: I agree this needs more doc or a good article. You can find an (a bit complex) example in the ST_ExtractToRaster() function of the PostGIS Addons: https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons/blob/master/postgis_addons.sql

Comment: Sorry for being slow to accept, I hadn't had a chance to try it out. I attempted this! I must've used double quotes instead of single. I'm still quite new to PostGIS and frequenty have that problem!